# 'Need Authorization' error while trying to import proxy files using java

Tags: java

While trying to import proxy files using the command as given below:
wsimport.exe http://X.XXX.X.XX/webservices2/CoreService2011.svc?wsdl a error occurs.

i.e:
 needs authorization, please provide authorization file with read access at #rootdirectory/.metro/auth or use -Xauthfile to give the author and on each line provide authorization information using this format
://user:password@host:port//

But i am not able to find .metro folder at the location

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: did you check with Authentication for Webservices application in IIS set to Anonymous? - I am not sure why it is webservices2 in your URL BTW

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I originally mentioned the proxy that comes with the installation, but that is for .NET only.

Since you are connecting using Java, it's a little more complicated. 
However, the recommended approach is outlined in the documentation:

[Interacting with the Core Service from Java](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B2C3F336-0051-4576-8FFB-06A068CAA31F)

As mentioned on the sub-page '[Getting the Java proxy client up and running](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-CF2ABF27-2D1C-4342-9635-2DFD7A6D4D42)', the *XmlBeans* proxy generator is recommended over other ones like *wsimport*.

Could you try the approach outlined in that section and report back if that worked for you? Note that the following links are for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. You didn't specify the version you were using, so you may need to search for the equivalent topic in the documentation for your version. I'm fairly sure the steps haven't changed much, though.

Comment: That won't work with Java :)

Comment: You're right. I was thinking it was wsdl.exe but wsimport.exe is indeed the Oracle equivalent.